# UFT 12.02 not identifying chrome browser objects. Its treating browser as Windws object

Tags: google-chrome, qtp, hp-uft

I have selected recorded mode as "Web" with option "Record and Run on any browser". Also added Mandotory and Assestive property for web elements.

But when I spy object of chrome it detects chrome as Wpfobject under Windows option.

Does anyone have an idea of how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Check if the UFT extension is activated in the browser

Comment: Yes it is enabled. But stil having the same issue